# Which is a better poison to the Haber's process, $\ce{CO}$ or $\ce{H2S}$?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, catalysis, iron

I am studying about catalysts and their promoters and poisons and came across two of the possible poisons for Fe used during Haber's process and wanted to compare their effect on the rates of reaction. Which of them would lower the rate of reaction of Haber's process more, $\ce{CO}$ or $\ce{H2S}$?

Comment: Wikipedia states: Sulfur compounds, phosphorus compounds, arsenic compounds, and chlorine compounds are permanent catalyst poisons. Oxygenic compounds like water, carbon monoxide, carbon dioxide and oxygen are temporary catalyst poisons.[3][35] Permanent trumps temporary? I have no access to the publication though, maybe you can get it yourself.